# ReactJS - setState cloned object or forceUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

In my state in React application, I have one object that is organized similar to tree structure. User can modify any node in that tree, from root to leaf. There are 3 levels in tree (depth = 3), and each level is rendered with specific function. When user update data, in order to re-render, I have two options:

- Clone this object to another new object, using strategy like DFS to traverse whole tree and find out the node needs modified, then setState this object.
- Directly mutate the node insides render function, then call forceUpdate from most-top components.

Are there any comparison between above methods or other ideal solutions?

Comment: The second one is almost never suggested. Maybe there's a third way. But among the above two, i would definitely suggest (1)

Comment: The tree you have is a shallow one. If you can organize your content such that searching the tree is O(1), there's no reason to go for the second method.

Comment: Generally speaking, don't use forceUpdate(); using setState() to update your data as it causes a re-render using that new data. So the first one in that list is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

`Clone this object to another new object, using strategy like DFS to traverse whole tree and find out the node needs modified, then setState this object.`

Seems like the best option for you. This way every time the `state` that you're modifying changes, your component would re-render without needing anything extra. [Here](https://davidwalsh.name/react-force-render) and [here](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) you have articles in witch is explain why you never have to use `forceUpdate`.